# Unable to contact smtp aspmx.l.google.com via .NET script

Tags: .net, email, smtp

A customer has a software wrote in .NET that they want to setup to send email via Google Smtp without SSL authentication. Here's the script that concern the smtp part:

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("aspmx.l.google.com", 25);
MailMessage message = new MailMessage("sender@domain.com", "recipient@domain.com", "Test from  .NET", "sent from Google");
client.Send(message);
```

We get the error "unable to contact the server" we have try also replacing aspmx.l.google.com with the IP but same error

Do you know what is wrong?

Best Regards,
Andrea

Answer (score 1):

At a glance it looks like your using the wrong address, if you are attempting to use google as a smtp server then you need to use smtp.gmail.com on port 465 sll/587 tls.

The address your using aspmx.l.google.com is googles restricted smtp server and can only send to gmail / google app users. So your email To of @Domain.com will not work, @Gmail.com would work.

Also check your firewall and AV - I find my AV blocks the call my requests from time to time.

Google docs on this - https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en